# How to Exclude a Specific Row from a Find Last Column Function

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a spreadsheet that creates an inventory list. The Macro i'm writing opens my intranets search page, enters the catalog number in row a (not shown in image). and returns information to the excel sheet. As it enters locations (RIG), It creates a header in row 2. I created a second macro that removes inactive locations. After this filter, I'm left with a cleaner list, but I want to remove the header in row 2 that no longer has information below it (i.e. columns AH, AI, AJ and so on). I know I can find the last used column of the worksheet, but what i want to do is clear formatting , border and contents in row2 whenever row3 to lastrow is empty.

Is there a way to adjust this to exclude the row2 from the search?

```
Dim LastColumn As Integer

Set LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _ 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Cells(2,LastColumn).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1)
 Do
 If not ActiveCell = "" Then
  ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete(xlToLeft)
  DoEvents
 Else
  Exit Do
 End If
 Loop
```

[image: My Search SHeet]

**Final Code after incorporating Gary's Students Response. Thank you!!**

```
 'Find last used column below header row
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim N As Long
Dim rCol As Range

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Do
For N = Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set rCol = Cells(1, N).EntireColumn
    If wf.Subtotal(103, rCol) > 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Next
Loop

Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Cells(2, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False

 'Trim header row to used columns only
Cells(2, N).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

 Do
    If Not ActiveCell = "" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete (xlToLeft)
        DoEvents
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude the row from the examination:

```
Sub FindLastColumn()
    Dim BadRow As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim N As Long, rCol As Range, i As Long
    BadRow = 7
    i = 103
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Cells(BadRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    For N = Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set rCol = Cells(1, N).EntireColumn
        If wf.Subtotal(i, rCol) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "The last used column is:   " & N
            Cells(BadRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next N
    Cells(BadRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, I was not aware of ".entirerow.hidden = true". This will hide it from being visible on the sheet, will that mean that the find function wont be able to see it?

Answer (score 0):

So basically from what I can understand you are trying to do a search and exclude some rows from the search? Why not use a double loop?

```
for i 1 to columns you want
    for j = 1 to rows you want
        if j <> row you don't want
            'add code here
        end if
    nextj
next i
```

Comment: because the column length will change. Im trying to use the find function to find the "columns you want" number.